# What are the risks of having two servers communicating over http?

Tags: security, ssl, https

I understand how you can listen to some local network, and steal cookies or data when a client-server traffic is not ssl-secured.

But what about two servers talking to each other ?

For instance, if api `A` is sending sensitive data to api `B`, what are the odds to be spied on ?

Is it possible, easy or unlikely for the http requests to be intercepted ?

[edit]: The point is not to know wether it is secured or not (I know it is not), but merely to understand what could really happen, and what's going on under the hook :)

Thanks

Comment: Bottom line is it's not secure, so don't expect security.

Comment: Of course I don't expect no security, but the point was to try to have a better understanding of what's happening under the hook !

Comment: router, switches, other network infrastructure might be looking at packets going between servers just for logging purposes, as which point the data can be easily reassembled

Answer (score 0):

- Network can inject ads
- Network can inject viruses
- Network can steal passwords

Nothing can go well !